# Jest mock an import from a utility file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to standardise the way that regularly mocked functions get mocked.

So I have a function which handles a call to a home screen context in `useHomeScreenContext.ts`.

```
export const useHomeScreenContext = () => useContext(/* context here */)
```

Then the component I am testing uses that hook
`Component.tsx`

```
export const Component = () => {
    const context = useHomeScreenContext();
}
```

Then my test file for Component looks like
`Component.test.tsx`

```
const contextSpy = jest.spyOn(context, 'useHomeScreenContext');
it("works", () => {
    contextSpy.mockReturnValue(fakeValue)
    expect(fakeValue).toBeTruthy()
})
```

The issue that I have with this approach is that there will be a large number of files that will need to be tested by mocking this context and the actual mock is a little bit more complex than I have put in here. So what I would like to do is to standardise the mock using a utility function, so I have created a separate file called `mockHomeScreenContext.ts` which looks a little something like this.

```
const contextSpy = jest.spyOn(context, 'useHomeScreenContext');
export const mockHomeScreenContext = (context) => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    contextSpy.mockReturnValue(mergeDeepLeft(context, homeScreenContextDefaults));
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    contextSpy.mockRestore();
  });
};
```

With the idea being that it is used inside of a describe block and it will tidy itself up at the end of the describe block like so

```
describe('and does not have funds', () => {
    mockHomeScreenContext(contextOverrides);
    it("works", () => {
        // Tests here
    })
});
```

And this seems to work really well, until I have 2 describe blocks and then things start to go a bit haywire and some tests seem to mock the data correctly but then all following tests will fail as the mock function is not returning anything. Getting rid of the `afterAll` call to clean up the mock helps but it then infects other tests.

I have been round and round in circles for days trying to get this working and I feel like it really shouldnt be this difficult and I am just missing a little bit of an understanding as to how jest mocks work.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64932507/861993

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the fact that your `contextSpy` is global for all tests, because it's created outside of `mockHomeScreenContext` function. As you can find in [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockrestore), `mockRestore` would `restore the original (non-mocked) implementation`. You might try to use `mockClear` instead, as it's a softer version (I usually just use that).

However, I would propose to not mock your context like this, but rather create a mock provider that would cause `context` to work properly, without a need to do extensive mocking (which as you probably see can be quie painful).

Here's example of what I have in mind:

Usage in test:

```
<MockProvider context={contextOverrides}>
  <YourComponent/>
</MockProvider>
```

And implementation:

```
const MockProvider = ({context, children}) => {
  return (
    <YourContext.Provider value={mergeDeepLeft(context, homeScreenContextDefaults)}>
      {children}
    </YourContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

This way you would get rid of all those hard mocks and would use real context (with some mocked value).